# MPAndroidChart how to set a dual-background color on the chart

Tags: android, bitmap, mpandroidchart

I am using the latest MPAndroidChart library, and I was wondering if there is way to set a dual-background color on the chart.  I need the colors to match a certain number of days that will be displayed on the x-axis.  I would like to be able to do this programmatically as I will be using real time data, so the background will be set to a certain no. of days and move along as the chart is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to **programmatically create a bitmap** that always changes according to the latest realtime data you get. Then, you use that `Bitmap` and set it as the chart-background.

There is no way to set a specific background color (or multiple) in the way you describe it other than via the methods and ways the `View` class itself already provides.

Comment: Okay Phillip, thanks for the quick reply.  I was looking at doing it that way it does seem intensive to redraw the bitmap each time, thanks for the library, best I seen so far.

Comment: Hi Philip, I have created the bitmap image and have it displaying in the background with the grid color set to transparent. Is there now a way to hide everything outside of the grid. If i use setBackgroundColor it overrides the image, any info would be helpful.

Comment: @Philipp Jahoda Can you please illustrate the simple example to implement this.

Comment: Is it still the only way to do it? I need horizontal areas of various colors, for various Y axis values ranges.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the style that I wanted I downloaded the source-code and edited it to allow me to add a Bitmap image to the graph background. So now the background is redrawn when new data is entered and then added to the graph background so that it looks like the date is linked to the background color.  Thanks again to Philipp Jahoda for the brilliant library and thank god for open source developers.

p.s if I ever get rich off of this app I will look after you.